# What does the Type declaration with type Class/interface name mean?

Tags: php

I am sorry I am still new to PHP by now and my questions may sound a bit ridiculous but i wonder what is the sense of the Type declaration of type Class/interface name? This was invented in PHP 5.0.0. I have searched also on stackoverflow but I did not found helpful information... In the php.net Documentation there are some examples for class type declaration but I did not really understand...

What I understand with class type declaration is:
The parameter must be an instanceof the given class or interface name. And I know that the parameter name of the variable is usually the same of the class certainly the variable is starting with Dollar sign and staring with lowercase. But I understand the other types better which are listed on http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

And there is Example #7 Basic class type declaration

```
class C {}
class D extends C {}

// This doesn't extend C.
class E {}

function f(C $c) {
    echo get_class($c)."\n";
}

f(new C);
f(new D);
f(new E);
```

The class C is empty, but what is if there is Code (for example some properties and methods) in it?

There are also Return type declarations:

So please can you help me with this:

```
public function test(): Class {}
```

When do i have to define the : and the Class and what is the purpose of it and how does it work?
I would also look forward if you have maybe some links with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [docs here](http://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php).

It says that the function test must return a value of Class (your code isn't correct, you should specify a valid class, like C,D or E in your case

Take this code for example:

```
class A {}
class B {
    public function test(): A {}
}

$b = new B;
$b->test();
```

It will throw an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of B::test() must be an instance of A, none returned

Now, if you define a correct return, it works:

```
public function test(): A {
    return new A;
}

$b = new B;
var_dump($b->test());
```

Output:

```
object(A)
```

Comment: There is a little typo, the variable should not be $B it should be $b. Then your Code is working. Thanks a lot! Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
//here we can only check class declaration name.no property or method should be access for any other check
```

class C {

```
public $abc = "Tn million";

public function my_func(){
    echo "hello";
}
```

}

class D extends C {}

// This doesn't extend C.
class E {}

function f(C $c) {

```
echo get_class($c)."\n";
```

}

f(new C);//C

f(new D);//D

f(new E);//Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to f() must be an instance of C, instance of E given, called

Comment: Please format your reply, it is hard to read. Please also check [Answering Reccomendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)